# xCode 12.5.1 App Icon not showing although it is there

Tags: xcode

I have an ongoing issue in Xcode 12.5.1

[image]

All my icons are perfectly fine and added.
But on the upper left corner, the **icon will not show up** since the latest Xcode update.

Furthermore, when archiving and trying to upload my app, it gives me the following **error**:

```
error itms-90022: "missing required icon file. the bundle does not contain an app icon for iphone / ipod touch of exactly '120x120' pixels
```

[image]

But this icon is definitely there and it's also in the correct folder.
My manifest looks also fine.

Things I tried:
I mainly worked through this thread:
[Xcode 10 app icon not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771256/xcode-10-app-icon-not-showing)

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68000523/2052543 => this code is not there when checking `Show Package Contents -> project.pbxproj`
2. Top rated answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54642570/2052543 but here I don't have the possibility to check this checkbox (its greyed out), see:

[image]

3. I cleared Xcode Build
4. I removed the `Images.xcassets` folder completely and re-added it
5. I removed each icon step by step and then re-drag/dropped it back into Xcode

All this didn't change the issue. Still the small icon is blank + the error appears when I try to send my build to Appstore Connect.

It was working fine in Xcode 12.5 but since the upgrade to 12.5.1 this all started to get weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that some older commit modified the file `myApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

I added back these lines

```
13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A /* Resources */ = {
            isa = PBXResourcesBuildPhase;
            buildActionMask = 2147483647;
            files = (
                81AB9BB82411601600AC10FF /* LaunchScreen.storyboard in Resources */,
                13B07FBF1A68108700A75B9A /* Images.xcassets in Resources */,
            );
            runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
        };
```

and now I can re-select the target + the icon is back